# Finding data in an Excel table

Tags: excel, match, vlookup

I have an table in my Excel worksheet that looks like the following:
[image: princing table]

I am trying to figure out how to use VLOOKUP (or similar) to return a value in a cell based on two other cells. The first cell has the string "STANDARD" or one of the other 2 and the second cell has a number in it for the price. I am trying to find the price (3rd column) for the combination of the first cell and the value in the second cell within the range. So cell A1 has STANDARD and B1 has 12.00, I would like to have 13.99
Or cell A1 has NONSTANDARD and B1 has 1000.00, I would get 139.99

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Objective:** To find the value in the `3rd column` that corresponds to the `1st column` & `2nd column` combination, where the `2nd column` represents a range with the minimum value to which the `3rd column` corresponds, i.e.:

| If 1st Column | and 2nd Column | then 3rd Column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Standard | 225 | 23.99 |
| StandardPlus | 525 | 44.99 |
| NonStandard | 1234 | 1699.99 |

Assuming that the table is located at `[F1:H15]` and the following values located at `[A1:B2]` enter this standard formula in `[C1:C2]`:

```
= IFERROR( INDEX( $H$1:$H$15, AGGREGATE( 14, 6, ROW(C:C) /
  ( ($F$1:$F$15=A1) * ($G$1:$G$15<=B1) ), 1 ) ), TEXT(,) )
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SUMIFS()` even though nothing is being summed here:

```
 =SUMIFS(C:C, A:A,"STANDARD", B:B, 0)
```

Would return "13.99"